# Check if array of ANY type contains element

Tags: c#, arrays

I have two parameters I receive using reflection that could be of different types.

```
object array;
object value;
```

...

```
array=new int[] { 1,2,3};
value=3;
```

...

```
array=new string[] { "one","two","three"};
value="two";
```

I want to find out if `value` is inside `array`, no matter which type.
The following command does *not* compile:

```
bool isInside=Array.Exists(array, q=>q==value);
```

> The type arguments for method 'Array.Exists(T[], Predicate)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Why would you even store an array inside an object in the first place? Use real types and all this goes away. Or even better, use something like `List<T>`.

Comment: `Array.IndexOf((Array) array, <value>) >= 0` should work regardless of array type and item value. It is not what you'd call elegant or efficient, though. (You need even more care for arrays that aren't 0-bounded, but the existence of those is mostly ignored in C#.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way I can think of is to cast the array to `Array`, then use a for loop to search through it:

```
var castedArray = (Array)array;
for (int i = 0 ; i < castedArray.Length ; i++) {
    if (castedArray.GetValue(i).Equals(value)) {
        Console.WriteLine("It exists!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that `==` won't work here because `int`s will be boxed.

If your arrays only have one dimension, `Array.IndexOf` would work as well (with `castedArray` and `value`), but if you want to handle 2D or 3D arrays as well, you need to check the `Rank` and use nested for loops.

Answer (score 1):

OS it is still an Array. So lets start with defining the variables as

```
Array array;
object value;
```

Array is IEnumerable we can define an extension class:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool HasItem(this IEnumerable enumerable, object value)
    {
        return enumerable.OfType<Object>().Any(e => e.Equals(value));
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
 Array array = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
 object value = 1;

 //false because the value is a string.
 var result = array.HasItem("1");
```

if you need it to be true some convertion logic should be added to HasItem method

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory answer using LINQ:

```
//using System.Linq;
//using System.Reflection;
public static bool IsInArrayUnkownType(object array, object obj)
{
    Type type = array.GetType().GetElementType();
    MethodInfo contains = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Contains").First();
    MethodInfo containsUnGenericated = contains.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { type });
    object result = containsUnGenericated.Invoke(null, new object[] { array, obj });
    return (bool)result;
}
```

EDIT: Looking ot other solutions, I wouldn't really recommand this one, as reflection is slow and others did it far more elegantly.

Comment: Yes, reflection is an awful way to solve this problem, why would you even suggest it?

Comment: @DavidG To be honest - mostly to see if it can be done that way.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this one

```
var dynamicArray = (object[])array;
bool isInside = dynamicArray.Contains(value);
```

Comment: How do you expect to cast `int[]` to `object[]`?